# Fractional shares

Tags: stocks, trading, broker, fractional-shares

Some brokers offer fractional shares. So when i buy half share of stock (0.5) whose buy the rest half of share because in stock exchanges(e.g. nyse,nasdaq,bats) you can only exchange whole shares.